# Keep the highlighted background color on expanded comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

I like the fact that when I click the "show more comments" link under a post, that the previously hidden comments flash their backgrounds when they appear. I believe this flashing behavior is a relatively new feature.

And now on to my feature request - Can the backgrounds on the expanded comments permanently retain the flashed (highlight) color? This would make it easier to tell which comments were just expanded.

So if we look at this example image, we see the initial comments with a white background, and the expanded (previously hidden) comments permanently highlighted:

---

> [image: comments-with-permanent-hilighting]

---

Comment: I would like to second this request a lot.  Almost on every occasion that more than 2 new comments show up my photographic memory fails me and I am not able to trivially determine which comments I have read and which ones were highlighted a moment ago and still require reading.  If reading in other than my familiar languages there is no chance of even scanning the new comment start words to remember which ones are new.  If a lot of messages appear they do so out of view and make it very difficult to determine which ones were previously read.

Answer (score 2):

The fading animation could be kept, but instead of fading to pure white, it could fade to a light-greyish colour, since whether comments are hidden in long comment areas seems to be determined by the amount of votes they have (and its helpfulness).

I do like KalleMP's suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the highlighting could fade away MUCH slower if it HAS to fade for some historical UI policy reasons.  It could even fade away in proportion to the number of comments or the character count that were highlighted.